# Do buttons with 2 states ON/OFF exist in osx cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I need a button that remains pressed when clicked. Until the next click. Similar to the behavior of On/Off buttons in iOS or checkbox fields in osx.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

#### NSButtonType

Represent the button types that can be specified using setButtonType:.

```
enum {
   NSMomentaryLightButton   = 0,
   NSPushOnPushOffButton    = 1,
   NSToggleButton           = 2,
   NSSwitchButton           = 3,
   NSRadioButton            = 4,
   NSMomentaryChangeButton  = 5,
   NSOnOffButton            = 6,
   NSMomentaryPushInButton  = 7,
   NSMomentaryPushButton    = 0, // Deprecated, use NSMomentaryLightButton
   NSMomentaryLight         = 7, // Deprecated, use NSMomentaryPushInButton
};
typedef NSUInteger NSButtonType;
```

#### I'd say you want a NSPushOnPushOffButton